# How to control where in my window or JFrame panels appear

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

this has seriously been the biggest issue in my code. I just want to create a simple pizza order taker using multiple panels. I want to be able to dictate the specific area each panel is located. Can someone please just pretend I'm a complete idiot and help me point this out?

I've attached my code as well as an image of how it looks so far. I want to be able to place individual segments like getting the user's information, choosing pizza size, then toppings, then a section where I will display the receipt with all of the order total.

I can do the calculations and take in values, I just need to figure out the appearance.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;

public class PIZZA extends JFrame {
    Container window = getContentPane();
    ButtonGroup ordertype;
    JRadioButton delivery, takeout;
    JRadioButton small, medium, large;
    JLabel fname, phonenum, zipcode;
    JTextField ufname, uphonenum, uzipcode;
    JPanel userinfoinput;
    JPanel delivery_type;
    JPanel userinfolabel;
    JButton start;
    BoxLayout userbox, labelbox, deliverybox;
    ImageIcon starticon = new ImageIcon("start.png");
    public PIZZA() {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PIZZA frame = new PIZZA();
        new PIZZA();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("KRUSTY KRAB PIZZA");
        frame.deliverymethod();
        frame.getuserinfo();
        frame.userinfolabels();
        frame.getpizzasize();
        frame.toppings_meat();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void deliverymethod(){
        delivery_type = new JPanel();
        ordertype = new ButtonGroup();
        delivery = new JRadioButton("Delivery (Currently Unavailable)");
        delivery.setEnabled(false);
        takeout = new JRadioButton("Take Out");
        ordertype.add(takeout);
        ordertype.add(delivery);
        delivery_type.add(takeout);
        delivery_type.add(delivery);
        delivery_type.setSize(100,100);
        window.add(delivery_type,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    private void getuserinfo(){
        userinfoinput = new JPanel();
        //start = new JButton("Start", starticon);
        //start.setLayout(null);
        ufname = new JTextField(12);
        uphonenum = new JTextField(12);
        uzipcode = new JTextField(12);
        userinfoinput.add(ufname);
        userinfoinput.add(uphonenum);
        userinfoinput.add(uzipcode);
        //userinfoinput.add(start);
        GridLayout lay = new GridLayout(3,1);
        userinfoinput.setLayout(lay);
        window.add(userinfoinput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private void userinfolabels(){
        userinfolabel = new JPanel();
        fname = new JLabel("First Name");
        phonenum = new JLabel("Phone Number");
        zipcode = new JLabel("Zip Code");
        userinfolabel.add(fname);
        userinfolabel.add(zipcode);
        userinfolabel.add(phonenum);
        labelbox = new BoxLayout(userinfolabel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        GridLayout label = new GridLayout(3,1);
        userinfolabel.setLayout(label);
        window.add(userinfolabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private void getpizzasize(){
        JPanel pizzasize = new JPanel();
        ButtonGroup size = new ButtonGroup();
        small = new JRadioButton("Small");
        medium = new JRadioButton("Medium");
        large = new JRadioButton("Large");
        size.add(small);
        size.add(medium);
        size.add(large);
        pizzasize.add(small);
        pizzasize.add(medium);
        pizzasize.add(large);
        pizzasize.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pizzasize.setSize(100,100);
        window.add(pizzasize, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    private void toppings_meat(){
        JPanel meat = new JPanel();
        meat.setLayout(new BoxLayout(meat, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JCheckBox pepperoni = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
        JCheckBox meatball = new JCheckBox("Meatball");
        JCheckBox chicken = new JCheckBox("Grilled Chicken");
        JCheckBox sausage = new JCheckBox("Italian Sausage");
        JCheckBox bacon = new JCheckBox("Bacon");
        meat.add(pepperoni);
        meat.add(meatball);
        meat.add(chicken);
        meat.add(sausage);
        meat.add(bacon);
        window.add(meat);
    } 
}
```

Comment: *"I've attached my code as well as an image of how it looks so far."* There is no spoon .. err .. image.

Answer (score 0):

This pizza GUI uses several Swing layout managers in different `JPanels`.

[image: Pizza GUI]

The main layout managers that I want to talk about are the `JFrame` `BorderLayout` and the input form `GridBagLayout`.

A `BorderLayout` is rather flexible in that you can put Swing components in various locations.  The `JPanels` I created for this GUI are in the BEFORE_FIRST_LINE, CENTER, AFTER_LAST_LINE, and AFTER_LINE_ENDS positions of the `BorderLayout`.

The input form uses a `GridBagLayout` to position the `JLabels` and the input `JTextFields` in a column.  The `GridBagLayout` is more flexible than a `GridLayout` because the grid cells don't have to be the same size in a `GridBagLayout`.

The Oracle Swing tutorial [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) shows the different Swin layout managers, and how to use them.

Here's the code I used to create the pizza GUI.  I created each subordinate `JPanel` in a separate method.  All of the `JFrame` code is in the `run` method.  Separating different parts of the GUI allows me to focus on one part of the GUI at a time.  I can test each `JPanel` method separately.

I create the Swing components from left to right, top to bottom within a `JPanel`.  This allows me to visually verify that I've included all the appropriate methods for a component.  This also allows me to zero in on any component that isn't correct.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PizzaOrdering implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PizzaOrdering());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("KRUSTY KRAB PIZZA");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(getDeliveryMethodPanel(), 
                BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        frame.add(getUserInformationPanel(), 
                BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(getPizzaSizePanel(), 
                BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        frame.add(getMeatToppingsPanel(), 
                BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getDeliveryMethodPanel() {
        JPanel deliveryMethodPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        ButtonGroup orderTypeGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        JRadioButton takeoutRadioButton = 
                new JRadioButton("Take Out");
        orderTypeGroup.add(takeoutRadioButton);
        deliveryMethodPanel.add(takeoutRadioButton);

        JRadioButton deliveryRadioButton = 
                new JRadioButton("Delivery (Currently Unavailable)");
        deliveryRadioButton.setEnabled(false);
        orderTypeGroup.add(deliveryRadioButton);
        deliveryMethodPanel.add(deliveryRadioButton);

        return deliveryMethodPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getUserInformationPanel() {
        JPanel userInformationPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        userInformationPanel.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 1d;

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("First Name:");
        userInformationPanel.add(nameLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        JTextField userNameField = new JTextField(20);
        userInformationPanel.add(userNameField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel phoneNumberLabel = new JLabel("Phone Number:");
        userInformationPanel.add(phoneNumberLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        JTextField userPhoneNumberField = new JTextField(20);
        userInformationPanel.add(userPhoneNumberField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel zipCodeLabel = new JLabel("Zip Code:");
        userInformationPanel.add(zipCodeLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        JTextField userZipCodeField = new JTextField(20);
        userInformationPanel.add(userZipCodeField, gbc);

        return userInformationPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getPizzaSizePanel() {
        JPanel pizzaSizePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        ButtonGroup sizeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton smallRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Small");
        sizeGroup.add(smallRadioButton);
        pizzaSizePanel.add(smallRadioButton);

        JRadioButton mediumRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Medium");
        sizeGroup.add(mediumRadioButton);
        pizzaSizePanel.add(mediumRadioButton);

        JRadioButton largeRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Large");
        sizeGroup.add(largeRadioButton);
        pizzaSizePanel.add(largeRadioButton);

        return pizzaSizePanel;
    }

    private JPanel getMeatToppingsPanel() {
        JPanel meatToppingsPanel = new JPanel();
        meatToppingsPanel.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        meatToppingsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(
                meatToppingsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JCheckBox pepperoniCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
        meatToppingsPanel.add(pepperoniCheckBox);
        
        JCheckBox meatballCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Meatball");
        meatToppingsPanel.add(meatballCheckBox);
        
        JCheckBox chickenCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Grilled Chicken");
        meatToppingsPanel.add(chickenCheckBox);
        
        JCheckBox sausageCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Italian Sausage");
        meatToppingsPanel.add(sausageCheckBox);
        
        JCheckBox baconCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Bacon");
        meatToppingsPanel.add(baconCheckBox);

        return meatToppingsPanel;
    }

}
```